# Ruby and Git refuse to update. (Mac)

Tags: osx, git, ruby

I've been trying to update Git for a while. I'm currently stuck on 1.7.3.4, and I've tried updating to 1.7.4.x, and 1.7.5.x but it never works.

Today I compiled and installed Ruby 1.9.2, but it still shows up as 1.8.7.

I'm running 10.6.7 on a MacBook Pro.

I have no idea why it won't update. Any ideas? :(

Comment: How are you compiling them?

Comment: Which Git package did you install / update?

Comment: I just download Git from the website. I built Ruby with `autoconf` and `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, software compiled from source will install to `/usr/local/bin`. This is probably where you are installing your locally-compiled Ruby.

A common “downloadable” Git for Mac OS X is the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) pre-built version. It installs to `/usr/local/git/bin` (though I suppose you might have downloaded some other variant).

Neither of those directories are in the default PATH environment variable, so neither will be used when you type `ruby` or `git` into your shell.

However, the system-bundled Ruby (version 1.8.7) and the Git that comes with Xcode 4 (1.7.3.4, as I have read) are installed in `/usr/bin`, which is in the default PATH.

You probably just need to adjust your PATH in your shell initialization files. Just put your locally installed directories first.

---

If you are using *bash* (the default), add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

and make sure you have the following in your `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` (use whichever exists or `.bash_profile` if neither exist):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make things simple for yourself: Use *RVM* for Ruby, and *Homebrew* for git (and other stuff).

RVM installs multiple (if desired) different versions of Ruby for you, and lets you switch between them easily.

Homebrew is basically fink/macports done... well, better.  Much better.

- RVM: http://beginrescueend.com/
- Homebrew: https://brew.sh

Good luck!